# Can I configure Rails production to fail on startup if migrations are incomplete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is some issue going on with our staging server (staging environment is almost identical to production) where values for computed attributes aren't present for all the existing model objects. Of course, it works in my development environment.

The values are inserted by a migration. Problem is, since it's the kind of migration which just changes data in the database and doesn't change the schema, it's impossible to know whether the admin forgot to run it.

Meanwhile, when you run Rails tests, it refuses to run the tests at all if any migrations haven't been run. This sounds like something that should be done for production as well. I'm not sure why it isn't the default, but is there some way to do it?

**Update:**

I feel like I'm most of the way to figuring this out. There is a `db:abort_if_pending_migrations` task. I can't use the task, since I don't know whether the sysadmin will bypass that, but the code in it is useful.

So in an initialiser, I put:

```
pending_migrations = ActiveRecord::Migrator.open(ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrations_paths).pending_migrations

if pending_migrations.any?
  puts "You have #{pending_migrations.size} pending #{pending_migrations.size > 1 ? 'migrations:' : 'migration:'}"
  pending_migrations.each do |pending_migration|
    puts '  %4d %s' % [pending_migration.version, pending_migration.name]
  end
  abort %{Run `rails db:migrate` to update your database then try again.}
end
```

And this does work. But now there is a new problem - I can't run `db:migrate` either, since migrations also run the initialisers!

Is there a good way to tell the difference between Rails starting up to run migrations and other situations?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration/CheckPending

Comment: In my experience it usually does this by default by displaying a generic "We're sorry, something went wrong" message when you try to hit the site.  Is this something that you're not seeing when you visit the site?

Comment: you could just put a `rake db:migrate` shell call in your `application.rb`.

Comment: @Makoto Correct, the site loads as per normal, yes. The attribute in question just shows the null value everywhere. I think "We're sorry, something went wrong" only happens if you actually hit some code which fails. For instance, when we switched to Devise, the database still had crypted_password because the admin hadn't run that migration yet. That did show the "something went wrong" screen, but not because Rails had detected that the migration didn't run, just by pure luck that the login screen happened to use the attribute which changed.

Comment: @maxpleaner I'm scared that if the migration breaks, it might do something irreparable to the data. Usually it's better practice to do it as a deliberate step.